# Center text or contents of bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to center the content of the drop-down menu. Adding text-align: center and justify-contents: center hasn't worked. Have also added !important to css for these properties without luck.

My HTML- it has three dropdowns, with the same HTML (the dropdown div is repeated three times). If a Github repo would be easier to read, here's one: https://github.com/katez/Uni-Interview-Form-15-December-2017

```css
.dropdown-item {
  font-family: OpenSans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-secondary {
  width: 58px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid#CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<main class="card-contents">
  <p>EXCEL</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
            type="button" 
            id="dropdownMenuButton" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            aria-expanded="false">+</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">+</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">++</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">+++</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to display the button as a rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you have to use bellow class inside the dropdown menu like this

```
<div class="dropdown-menu text-center" aria-  labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"> 
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">+</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">++</a> 
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">+++</a> 
 </div>
```

Comment: the content remains in the same spot with this class still. Is it possible this class doesn't work with bootstrap buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Do you necessarily want the button to be a rectangle? Your height parameter is the one causing problems... How about this:

```
#dropdownMenuButton {
  text-align:center;
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
}
```

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMKqoa

Comment: ... and adding something like `line-height: 5px;` or `padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;` to `#dropdownMenuButton` could shape it to a rectangle again...